# Pass multiple parameters to C# MVC action without knowing the exactly number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to C# MVC action without knowing the exactly number?

For example, I could pass

```
mywebsite.com/brands/gm/ford/fiat/dodge
```

OR

```
mywebsite.com/brands/gm/ford/fiat
```

However, I don't want to have to create a route like:

```
"brands/{brand1}/{brand2}/{brand3}/{brand4}"
```

Because a variable number of brands will be passed to it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, but only by using a wildcard param. Then, you're responsible for parsing the individual params out of the path yourself. For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Brands",
    "brands/{*brands}",
    new { controller = "Brands", action = "Index" }
);
```

Based on your first example URL, the value of the `brands` param would be the string `"gm/ford/fiat/dodge"`. You'd then need to break this up to get the individual brands:

```
public ActionResult Index(string brands)
{
    var brandList = brands.Split("/");

    // do something with `brandList`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you got a controller method:

```
public ActionResult Some(string brands)
{
    string[] individualBrands = brands.Split(';');

    return View();
}
```

The url would look like : http://localhost:50006/Home/Some?brands=brand1;brand2

Comment: In my case, I need for SEO purposes, slashed style.

Comment: Would look a bit weird though... definatly not standard... but that's a matter of taste really =)

Comment: @ramires.cabral: FWIW, what you're trying to achieve could actually work against you for SEO purposes. For example, `/brands/gm/ford` is a totally different URL from `/brands/ford/gm`, but your action would likely render the same content for both variants. This could result in duplicate content penalties if both URL forms get indexed.